# R: Using two databases to reach one outcome

Tags: r

I am new to R and am working on a research project but ran into issues trying to utilize both the datasets I have. I am trying to use a yearly weather data base to find the average precipitation for a timeframe within the other data set I have. However, the other database uses random single days (its various hatch dates for birds) and I want to generate an average for a timeframe set two weeks before to two weeks after the hatch date for each date I have (basically create an average for rain of a 4-week span with the hatch date in the middle). I am just not sure how to use the hatch date data to create a timeframe for the weather data to read. Sorry if anything is confusing or atypical as this is my first post and thanks to anyone who takes anytime for suggestions. I appreciate any and all responses.

Currently my main attempts centered around trying to use read_csv(HatchDate + 14) and read_csv(HatchDate - 14) and try and use that in an avg command for the other data. However, it was not really working and just gave me an error. After thinking I do not think this would work due to the variety of dates so I am just lost.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You've tried some approaches and elicited errors. Generally you would put those above to show your process, if you put three back tics above and below, it shows as 'code'.  The simplest approach I can think of is to pull precipitation (I'm assuming daily) as a column, add a daily date column, then pull in hatch_dates as a colunm(with NA between)...

Comment: Welcome to SO, DominicP! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: And for clarity of verbiage, the term "database" usually refers to an organized collection of data based on the use of a database management system (DBMS) (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), where the DMBS is often a server like postgres, sql server, mariadb, etc, or a file-based DBMS such as SQLite or DuckDB. Your mention of `read_csv` suggests simpler files. Your mention of `read_csv` suggests files only, meaning you have two _datasets_, not databases. I'm not intending to be pedantic, more that verbiage and terminology can confuse when non-standard.